# JavaScript Replacing Textarea Text with Base64

Tags: javascript, html, base64, decode, encode

I'm trying to make a quick base64 converter for an example project, and I was successful with outputting the text as an alert, but not when replacing the text in the textarea. Oddly, I was able to get it to work once, but once I refreshed the page to try again it stopped working. I tried JSFiddle, but it didn't show any errors in my JavSCript code, but it may be an issue with something else? Code below.

```
<h3>Decoders and Encoders</h3>
Base64 Decoder/Encoder<br>
<textarea name="base64-textarea" cols="50" rows="20" id="basesixfour"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Decode" id="inline left" onclick="base64-decode()">
<input type="submit" value="Encode" id="inline left" onclick="base64-encode()">

<script language="javascript">
function base64-decode() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('basesixfour').value;
    var base64-decode = atob(getText);
    document.getElementById('basesixfour').value = base64-decode;
}
function base64-encode() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('basesixfour').value;
    var base64-encode = btoa(getText);
    document.getElementById('basesixfour').value = base64-encode;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've typo-s
change:

```
base64-encode  ->  base64_encode
```

and

```
base64-decode  ->  base64_decode
```

```html
<h3>Decoders and Encoders</h3>
Base64 Decoder/Encoder<br>
<textarea name="base64-textarea" cols="50" rows="20" id="basesixfour"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Decode" id="inline left" onclick="base64_decode()">
<input type="submit" value="Encode" id="inline left" onclick="base64_encode()">

<script language="javascript">
function base64_decode() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('basesixfour').value;
    var base64_decode = atob(getText);
    document.getElementById('basesixfour').value = base64_decode;
}
function base64_encode() {
    var getText = document.getElementById('basesixfour').value;
    var base64_encode = btoa(getText);
    document.getElementById('basesixfour').value = base64_encode;
}
</script>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Sorry to be a noob. Is there a reason why JavaScript can't have variabled with a '-' in it? I looked into that at one point but did not find anything substantial.

Comment: of course '-'  is math operation, and because of it You cannot have variable with it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help.